# Import Error: No module named 'jupyter_cms'

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I am using conda version: 4.0 python: 3.4 on windows 8.1 64-bit.

Using Ipython notebook 4.1. `%load_ext jupyter_cms` gives an error:

> ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_cms'

I checked `conda install jupyter_cms` there is no package with this name in anaconda metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this link i believe you will get your answer: https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/contentmanagement

Specifically the 'Install It':

In Jupyter Notebook 4.1 and 4.0, you install and activate the extension like so:

## Install the python package

pip install jupyter_cms

## Register the notebook frontend extensions into ~/.local/jupyter

## See jupyter cms install --help for other options (e.g., --sys-prefix)

jupyter cms install --user --symlink --overwrite

## Enable the JS and server extensions in your ~/.jupyter

jupyter cms activate

In either case, you will need to restart your notebook server if it was running during the enable/activate step. Also, note that you can run jupyter --paths to get a sense of where the extension files will be installed.

Hope this helps.